# DataControlField, Parser Error Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I have a custom web control that inherits from DataControlField which has a property called MyProperty of type string.

When trying this inside a GridView column definition:

```
<MyField MyProperty='<%# MyGlobalResources.TheResourceIWant %>' />
```

Gives me this result:

> Parser Error Message: Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. Query.Web.DynamicField does not have a DataBinding event.

MyGlobalResources is a resx file in another project so I can't use the explicit localization notation (<%$ Resources: ResourceFile.ResourceName).

### What I have tried with no success:

- Use <%= instead of <%#.
- Mark MyField.MyProperty with Bindable(true).

Does anybody know what am I missing?

### Brief explanation of what I'm trying to accomplish:

I need to set the HeaderText property from code. Specifically from a resource file outside the webforms project (it is another project in the same solution) so <%$ Resources:... does not work.

The notation I'm trying to use works well inside a TemplateField (ie. in a LinkButton inside the ItemTemplate).

Thank you.

Comment: first of all what do you mean by outside the webforms project??? have you set the key rosource in webconfig file? do you want to to handle it by using global resoruce? if yes then check it out my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385285/overriding-default-resourceprovider/19611272#19611272

Comment: @SiddiqBaig: The resource file I need is in another project inside the solution. I have edited the question adding more detail. Thank you.